# Swimming Alone in a Pool

Tags: halacha, swimming

Is it written anywhere in Halacha that one is not allowed to swim alone? I recall once seeing it in the Rambam but can't seem to find it.
Thank you

Comment: It's generally a common-sense good practice, but the Rambam? Hm... the usual places for safety recommendations are Personality Traits Ch. 4 and Murderer & Preservation of Life, Chs. 11-12.  I didn't see it in either of those.

Comment: Yehuda, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for posing your question here! If the source exists, I hope someone can help you find it. Please consider clicking register, above, to create your account. This will allow you to take full credit for your contributions and will give you access to all of mi.yodeya's features.

Answer (score 3):

I do not recall seeing anything about swimming alone; besides for the standard Mitzva to protect your health/life.

However it is mentioned that one should not sleep alone in  a room and that one should not walk alone (on deserted road) at night. (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 33:7 and 71:2)

Comment: One shouldn't sleep alone in a room?  What if you are single, or your spouse is away over night, to say nothing of people who have their own room in all kinds of other circumstances?

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: I do not see in KSA 33:7, which is about reading the Torah, anything about sleeping alone or walking alone.  KSA 71:2 does warn against sleeping alone.  And on that I can ask my question.  But there is nothing about walking alone in either place.